# App resources vs a static variable

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

in my App.cs i have the following

```
private static LayoutManager layoutManager;
public static LayoutManager LayoutManager
{ 
    get { return layoutManager ?? (layoutManager = new LayoutManager()); } 
    set { layoutManager = value; } 
}
```

I need to access this variable from another Library so I defined it in the App XAML so I could use `Application.Current.FindResource("LayoutManager")`, without having to reference the project that contains the App, because i would get a circular dependency

```
<Managers:LayoutManager x:Key="LayoutManager"/>
```

- is adding an object to the resources the best option?
- what are the best programming practices in such case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two methods are essentially the same, the difference is mainly semantic.

As for your first question, adding an entry to a resource dictionary creates a new object, and places it in a dictionary of that scope (App, window, panel, etc.), this applies to anything you place in a resource dictionary, so the real question is what to place there. Resources placed in xaml are usually used by the xaml code (or something that affects it), it usually keeps styles, animations and so forth. You can, of course place anything you like there, but it's less common.

As for the best practice for this situation, I think you'll do better to place the object in a static property, since you try to access it in c#, and not in xaml. It gives you a little performance boost then trying to locate the resource, and you don't have to rely on magic strings, that won't give you a compile time error when if the property changes.

Comment: but the problem with static propery is that i need to add a reference in my other Lib to the prjoect that contains the App and i would get a circular dependency, or getting it using reflection

Comment: @user1492051 The same problem would happen if you place it in the xaml resources, you'll still need the reference. You need to think on how your project is designed to get by this. Try placing this property in the lowest assembly you can - a common assembly or something like it. Anyway, if you think it best, you can still place it in the resources, as I said, the difference is mainly semantic.

Comment: @no i used Application.Current.FindResource("LayoutManager") and its working perfectly, the library i am calling this from has no reference to the project that contains the app!

Comment: @user1492051 - Right, I misunderstood you, I thought the reference in the App assembly would cause the circular dependency. You can definitely use the app resources. Just be careful when you change the resource - The change won't affect the usages in the compile time, and you'll only get the error at runtime. Though I still think you should place a static property at a common assembly, or better yet, make the class a singleton. The fact that you _could_ get a circular dependency indicates that you may have a problem with your project's design.